# Representing multiple values with one character in Python

Tags: python, radix, items

I have 2 values that are in the range 0-31. I want to be able to represent both of these values in 1 character (for example in base 64 to explain what I mean by 1 character) but still be able to know what both of the values are and which came first.

Answer (score 4):

Find a nice Unicode block that has 1024 contiguous codepoints, for example [CJK Unified Ideographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs_(Unicode_block)), and map your 32*32 values onto them. In Python 3:

```
def char_encode(a, b):
  return chr(0x4E00 + a * 32 + b)

def char_decode(c):
  return divmod(ord(c) - 0x4E00, 32)

print(char_encode(17, 3))
# => 倣

print(char_decode('倣'))
# => (17, 3)
```

As you mention Base64... this is impossible. Each character in a Base64 encoding only allows for 6 bits of data, and you need 10 to represent your two numbers.

And also note that while this is only one character, it takes up two or three bytes, depending on the encoding you use. As noted by others, there is no way to stuff 10 bits of data into an 8-bit byte.

---

Explanation: `a * 32 + b` simply maps two numbers in range [0, 32) into a single number in range [0, 1024). For example, `0 * 32 + 0 = 0`; `31 * 32 + 31 = 1023`. [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) finds the Unicode character with that codepoint, but characters with low codepoints like `0` are not printable, and would be a poor choice, so the result is shifted to the beginning of a nice big Unicode block: `0x4E00` is a hexadecimal representation of `19968`, and is the codepoint of the first character in the CJK Unified Ideographs block. Using the example values, `17 * 32 + 3 = 547` and `19968 + 547 = 20515`, or `0x5023` in hexadecimal, which is the codepoint of the character `倣`. Thus, `chr(20515) = "倣"`.

The `char_decode` function just does all of these operations in reverse: if `a * p + b = x`, then `a, b = divmod(x, p)` (see [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod)). If `c = chr(x)`, then `x = ord(c)` (see [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)). And I am sure you know that if `w + r = y`, then `r = y - w`. So in the example, `ord("倣") = 20515`; `20515 - 0x4E00 = 547`; and `divmod(547, 32)` is `(17, 3)`.

Comment: Ha, I had already made the exact [same](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw9hI04pLQaGgKDOvRENdXS8rPzNPIzmjSMOgwiTVwEA7U8vYSDtLUwGkLQtFm6bm//8A) choice :-)

Comment: Thank you this works very well. For the future how do I find, look at, and use Unicode blocks if I decided to make one with a different choice instead of CJK Unified Ideographs?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block

Comment: Ha, I didn't know the first block is called "Basic Latin". I guess someone didn't want to give the Americans the satisfaction :-)

Comment: As I learn new parts of coding I like to understand them properly so could someone explain to me what is happening in these parts:
 chr(0x4E00 + a * 32 + b)
 divmod(ord(x) - 0x4E00, 32)

Answer (score 1):

Values [0, 31] can be stored in 5 bits, since `2**5 == 32`. You can therefore unambiguously store two such values in 10 bits. Conversely, you will not be able to unambiguously retrieve two 5-bit values from fewer than 10 bits unless some other conditions hold true.

If you are using an encoding that allows 1024 or more distinct characters, you can map your pairs to characters. Otherwise you simply can't. So ASCII is not going to work here, and neither is Latin1. But pretty much any of the "normal" Unicode encodings are fine.

Keep in mind that for something like UTF-8, the actual character will take up more than 10 bits. If that's a concern, consider using UTF-16 or so.

Comment: @Mad Physicist how do I use that to know both my values while still only have ONE SINGLE character.

Comment: For reference, one character is 8 bits, and you can't store 10 bits (2 0-31 values) in 8 bits.

Comment: @SuperStormer. A single character *can* be 8 bits, but certainly isn't in many cases.

Comment: @SuperStormer This is not correct. If we were talking about C, you might have a point, as `char` is defined as a 8-bit integral type; in Python 3, it is variable, and can be up to 32-bit. For example, the character "中" is at codepoint 20013, which is way beyond the 8-bit range.

Comment: @MadPhysicist so you are saying I have to assign 1023 characters? That is a lot of characters to assign that is why I am checking

Comment: I think you mean Unicode, not Unicode encodings.